# How to stack Sprites rendered inside Iterator?

Tags: quartz-composer

I am rendering an image to a Sprite inside of an Iterator. I'd like each render (iteration) to remain on the canvas indefinitely, so that each successive render layers on top of the previous ones. How can I do this?
There are no Clears or any other layers in my composition.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a bunch of images that I would like to display as a mosaic, similar to the iTunes cover screen saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quartz Composer, you'll almost always want to use a `Clear` patch — don't assume that you can rely on the prior contents of the framebuffer.  So, to accomplish this, you'll need to load all of your images into a structure (probably by using `JavaScript` to feed an `Image Loader` patch and build a `Queue` from that), and then display all of the images each frame using an `Iterator`.

Check out Apple's "Image TV" sample composition, available in the OS X Developer Library in the [Quartz Composer Conceptual Compositions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Conceptual/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009227) bundle.  This example demonstrates how to load a series of images into a structure and then display them.